# Adding a list as row and column indices to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   4.8 2.1 0  6.2  0
1   8.5 4.9 0  2.2  0
2   0   5.3 6  9.3  0
```

and two lists:
`ind=[ind1,ind2,ind3]` and `col=[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5]`

I want to rename the dataframe index and columns such that:

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
ind1 4.8  2.1   0    6.2  0
ind2 8.5  4.9   0    2.2  0
ind3  0   5.3   6    9.3  0
```

I tried converting the list to a dataframe and append by `df.append(col)`and `df.append(ind)`. But this did not work (probably because the indices of the df are different from that of the col and ind dataframes)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### with `set_axis`

```
df.set_axis(ind, inplace=False).set_axis(col, axis=1, inplace=False)

      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ind1   4.8   2.1     0   6.2     0
ind2   8.5   4.9     0   2.2     0
ind3   0.0   5.3     6   9.3     0
```

Current version of Pandas requires the use of `inplace=False`.  Future versions will have `inplace=False` as the default.  This would reduce the code to

```
df.set_axis(ind).set_axis(col, axis=1)
```

This would parallel usage of `set_index`.  The main difference between the uses of `set_index` and `set_axis` for the purposes of `axis=0` is that `set_index` requires a Numpy array while `set_axis` works with a list.  `set_index` does **not** work with a list because it interprets a list as a list of columns for which to use its values as elements in a MultiIndex.

---

I like [**user3483203**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522285/2336654)'s use of `rename`.  You can also pass `callable`s to the arguments.  This is a handy way to deal with adding generalized prefixes to both indices and columns

```
def prefix(t):
    def p(x):
        return f"{t}{int(x)+1}"
    return p

df.rename(index=prefix('ind'), columns=prefix('col'))

      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ind1   4.8   2.1     0   6.2     0
ind2   8.5   4.9     0   2.2     0
ind3   0.0   5.3     6   9.3     0
```

Comment: Very nice update, did not know you could pass callables!

Answer (score 3):

Recreate your df

```
ind = ['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3']  
col = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
pd.DataFrame(df.values,columns=col,index=ind)
Out[377]: 
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ind1   4.8   2.1   0.0   6.2   0.0
ind2   8.5   4.9   0.0   2.2   0.0
ind3   0.0   5.3   6.0   9.3   0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **`rename`** and **`f-strings`** if you want to avoid having to create the initial lists:

```
df.rename(
    index={i: f'ind{i+1}' for i in df.index},
    columns={i: f'col{int(i)+1}' for i in df.columns}
)

      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ind1   4.8   2.1     0   6.2     0
ind2   8.5   4.9     0   2.2     0
ind3   0.0   5.3     6   9.3     0
```

If this was just a sample naming convention and you are following another pattern, I would recommend using [@piRSquared's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522307/3483203) answer.

Comment: interesting method :-)

Comment: I Think this is cleaner `df.rename(index=dict(zip(df.index, ind)), columns=dict(zip(df.columns, col)))`

Comment: Oh I agree if they are using their lists still, I was trying to propose an alternative that avoided having to create initial lists like they have.  If those lists are just placeholders for something else this method isn't that helpful

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after the comment.  In fact you inspired me to add an alternative to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.set_index(ind)

df.columns = col
```

Comment: Setting the index with a list like this doesn't work, at least with my version... however, you could do `df.set_index(pd.Series(ind))`

Comment: This works in my version at least, not sure what's up with yours

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df.index = ind

df.columns = col

>>> df
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ind1   4.8   2.1     0   6.2     0
ind2   8.5   4.9     0   2.2     0
ind3   0.0   5.3     6   9.3     0
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me...this ends up NaNing the whole dataframe

Comment: Interesting. What version of `pandas` are you using? I'm on `0.21.1`